# Can I cancel just one Battle Menu order?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-x

While in combat, I can open the Battle Menu by pressing <kbd>+</kbd>, and then issue orders to my party. This is handy for various situations, such as using the "Keep you tension up!" order when I want to be using a lot of Overdrive.

However, sometimes I want to cancel an order. I know using the "Do as you please!" order will reset my party members back to the default combat strategy, but that will remove all orders I've sent.

My question is, **is it possible to cancel just one order at a time from the Battle Menu?**

For example, I may have used "Concentrate fire!", "Use melee attacks!" and "Keep your tension up!", but then want my party to go back to standard melee and ranged fighting (i.e. revert the "Use melee attacks!" order). Do I really have to issue "Do as you please!" and then reissue "Concentrate fire!" and "Keep you tension up!" every time? It becomes particularly tedious doing that almost every single battle.

Unfortunately the in game manual has very little information on the Battle Menu. All it states is:

> Order Companion: Order your party members to follow certain tactical plans.
>
> - Press <kbd>ZL</kbd>/<kbd>ZR</kbd> to toggle which party member you're issuing the order to.